# Regex to match characters to the right of a colon

Tags: regex, pcre

I'm stuck on a regex. I'm trying to match words in any language to the right of a colon **without matching the colon itself**.

The basic rule:

- For a line to be valid, it must not begin with or contain any characters outside of `[a-z0-9_]` until after `:`.
- Any characters to the right of `:` should match as long as the line begins with the set of characters defined above.

For instance, given a string such as these:

```
this string should not match

bob_1:Hi. I'm Bob. I speak русский and this string should match  

alice:Hi Bob. I speak 한국어 and this string should also match

http://example.com - would prefer to not match URLs

This string:should not match because no spaces or capital letters are allowed left of the colon
```

Only 2 of the 5 strings above need to match. And only to the right of the colon.

- **`Hi. I'm Bob. I speak русский and this string should match`**
- **`Hi Bob. I speak 한국어 and this string should also match`**

I'm currently using `(^[a-z0-9_]+(?=:))` to match characters to the left of `:`. I just can't seem to reverse the logic.

The closest I have at the moment is `(?!(?!:)).+`. This seems to match everything to right of the colon as well as the colon itself. I just can't figure out how to not include `:` in the match.

Can one of you regex wizards help me out? If anything is unclear please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short regex pattern (case insensitive):

```
^\w+:(\w.*)
```

- `\w` - matches any word character (equal to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`)

https://regex101.com/r/MZhqSL/6

---

As you marked `pcre`, here's the pattern you need (***only to the right of the colon***):

```
^\w+:\K\w.*
```

- `\K` - resets the starting point of the reported match. Any previously consumed characters are no longer included in the final match

https://regex101.com/r/E1yHVY/1

Comment: I'm trying to match characters to the right of the colon without matching the colon itself.

Comment: @I0_ol, see my `pcre` pattern

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex:

```
^[a-z0-9_]+:\K(?!//).*
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/OZAOO0/2)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `^`: Start
- `[a-z0-9_]+`: Match 1+ of `[a-z0-9_]` characters
- `:`: Match a colon
- `\K`: Reset matched info so far
- `(?!//)`: Negative lookahead to disallow `//` right after colon to avoid matching *potential* URLs
- `.*`: Match anything until end

Comment: I'm trying to not match the colon. Only characters to the right of it.

Comment: Then you can use: `^[a-z0-9_]+:\K(?!//).*` also remember `\w` will also match uppercase letter that you wrote you didn't want to match.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex: `^.*?:(.*)$`

`^.*?:` - from the beginning of the line, any character until the colon (non-greedy) included

`(.*)$` - use a matching group to anything that follows it till the end of the line

[Link to DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/HBUXCA/1)